# Connections do not close, and continue as ESTABLISHED and in the CloseableHttpClient will get stuck by that

Tags: java, connection, httpclient

I have a problem with the `CloseableHttpClient`:

After about two days I end up with 200 ESTABLISHED connections and my application stuck on a `client.execute`

Looks like a connection leak.

`netstat -a | grep address-portal.loc` gives me 200 lines like this:

```
cp6       0      0 mymachine.unix.i:38064 address-portal.loc.lo:https ESTABLISHED
```

My Java code :

```java
private static CloseableHttpClient getHttpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    return HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(getSSLContext()).setMaxConnTotal(20).setConnectionTimeToLive(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
}

public static List<Address> lookupAddress(String id, NominatimSourceType sourceType) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
    List<Address> reqResult;
    String apiCall = String.format(API_CALL_FORMAT_STR, getNominatimBaseUrl(sourceType), LOOKUP_URL_PRE_PART, id);
    LoggerService.logWhenDebug("API Call lookupAddress: " + apiCall, LOGGER);
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet(apiCall);
    CloseableHttpClient client = getHttpClient();
    try {
        LoggerService.logWhenDebug("before client.execute", LOGGER);
        // in the end the application hangs on this execute because of too many ESTABLISHED connections
        reqResult = client.execute(req, listAddressNominatimResponseHandler);
        LoggerService.logWhenDebug("client execute done", LOGGER);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        LoggerService.logWhenDebug("client.execute error: " + e, LOGGER);
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        req.releaseConnection();
        client.close();
        // below is used deprecated getConnectionManager() trying too fix the connections problem
        client.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
        client.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    return reqResult;
}
```

I am using Java version 11.0.20 and runnning on Tomcat version 9.0.55

Anybody has a clue?

I have tried adding the following code to fix the problem

```java
setMaxConnTotal(20)
setConnectionTimeToLive(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

And also used the deprecated function `getConnectionManager()` to try to close the connections

```java
client.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
client.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```